# Draw a vertical line in angular-nvd3 scatter chart

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, nvd3.js, angular-nvd3

I've got a angular-nvd3 scatter chart (similar to http://krispo.github.io/angular-nvd3/#/scatterChart) with two series of data. There is a requirement to add a few vertical reference lines to this graph to mark key dates.

[image]

The multichart works but I would lose the zoom function which is a key requirement.

Is there any way to add a vertical reference line in the scatter chart? TIA

Answer (score 1):

I just did it by a little bit cheating. I pushed this data in to my data array and adjust intercept until satisfied. I also search a lot but I couldn't find x_intercept option.

```
data.push({
       key: "Vertical",
       values: [],
       slope: 999,
         intercept:-500,
       });
```

Comment: How can I convert this into a horizontal line?